# Входная строка имела неверный формат. Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqlconnector, entity-framework-6

Всем доброго времени суток, пытаюсь решить эту проблему уже долгое время, не понимаю в чём беда.

Использую ORM Entity Framework 6 и СУБД MySQL. Пользовался проектом где то 2 недели всё хорошо было, вдруг исключение сегодня возникло. Возникает оно при создании таблицы т.е в `context.SaveChanges()`.

Поначалу всё было хорошо, пользовался недели 2 и, вдруг, сегодня получаю такое исключение.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
ex.StackTrace
   в System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   в System.Convert.ToDouble(String value)
   в MySql.Data.EntityFramework.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(CreateIndexOperation op)
   в MySql.Data.EntityFramework.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.<.ctor>b__22_4(MigrationOperation op)
   в MySql.Data.EntityFramework.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(IEnumerable`1 migrationOperations, String providerManifestToken)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.GenerateStatements(IList`1 operations, String migrationId)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass42_0.<Update>b__0()
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
   в System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
   в System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass66_0`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__0()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<>c.<InitializeDatabase>b__58_0(InternalContext c)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   в System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   в System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   в Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__67.MoveNext()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   в Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserValidator`2.<ValidateUserName>d__14.MoveNext()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserValidator`2.<ValidateAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.<CreateAsync>d__73.MoveNext()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.<CreateAsync>d__79.MoveNext()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   в OAuth2.InitializeDatabase.Initializer.<Create>d__1.MoveNext() в F:\\Programing\\ERP\\ERP Xamarin\\Web API\\OAuth2\\OAuth2\\InitializeDatabase\\Initializer.cs
```

```
 public class Initializer :DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public Initializer()
    {

        Create();
    }
    public async void Create()
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>(new CustomUserStore(new ApplicationDbContext()));
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<CustomRole, int>(new CustomRoleStore(new ApplicationDbContext()));

            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = "User1",
                Email = "qwerty@mail.ru",
                FirstName = "Вася",
                LastName = "Пупкин",
                NumberPassport = "123456789",
                PhoneNumber = "912342655675",
                UserSignature = "!@#dfsfsf2#@#!FGDFGDFGDAS!@#@",
            };

            WorkerCard card1 = new WorkerCard { BeginingTime = "8:00", EndTime = "16:30", Date = "7.27.2020", Day = "Sunday", Month = "july", Timeout = true, TotalWorkTime = 8, FK_User = user };

            context.WorkerCards.Add(card1);
            context.SaveChanges();



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я бы попробовал для начала всё время сделать до 12 часов и все даты с днём <=12. Если так прокатит, значит в базе с локализацией не лады - ожидает либо время в формате AM/PM и <=12, либо дату с месяцем на первом месте.

Comment: правильно ли я понял что Вы изменили структуру бд и после этого все поломалось? если да то как Вы выполнили миграцию?

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, код, который падает. Не скриншот, а именно код.

Comment: @Bald да было не больщое изменение но я у меня БД постоянно стирается. Так что миграции здесь не причём.

Comment: @SerafimProzorov я редактировал код, посмотрите пожалуйста сверху.

Comment: @ваняк, смотрите, Вы говорите, что миграции не при чем. Давайте обратим внимание на стектрейс: изначально исключение вылетело в методе ParseDouble, то есть при попытке где-то распарсить число с плавающей точкой на вход пришла некорректная строка. В том коде, который привели Вы этого не может случиться нигде, кроме того, он уж очень отличается от кода со скриншота чисто внешне. Смотрим стектрейс дальше: MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator, DbMigrator, всё говорит о том, что где-то что-то ломается при попытке применить миграцию.

Comment: @CrazyElf Изначально у меня  свойства дата и время определены в строковом формате чтоб в дальнейшем не мучаться. Да даже если я создаю любую другую сущность точно такая же ошибка вылетает, тут надо копать глубже. До этого всё работало и с таким же форматом датой и временем. Я тут на днях искал похожую ошибку как у меня и наткнулся на такую же проблему как и у меня [тут](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/661) ему написали что это проблема с провайдером в самом MySQL.

Comment: @Serafim Prozorov т.е если по вашим утверждениям получается что когда я физически захожу в MySQL Branch нажимаю Drop schema на свою БД, получается база данных не полностью удаляется а где то ещё и кэшируется? может быть и такое я этого незнаю, и в этом случае вы правы, хотя по сути всё должно удалятся. Но опять же если мы посмотри с другой стороны на исключения миграции то он конкретно пишет об этом что произошли изменения в классе и требуется миграция. Да я показал короткий кусок блока чтоб было наглядно понятно.

Comment: @ваняк, нет, конечно, такое вряд ли возможно. Однако, Вы же после того, как удалили всю базу, Вам же с чем-то работать надо, SaveChanges же куда-то сохранять эти самые изменения должен? Должен. Когда Вы запускаете приложение, я так думаю, у вас создается заново схема и к ней, естественно, применяются все миграции, которые у Вас есть, скорее всего какая-то из них и падает. Попробуйте сделать вот что: создайте схему руками, она вроде не такая сложная, уберите создание БД и накат миграций при запуске приложения, выполните этот же запрос. Результат тот же или нет?

Comment: @SerafimProzorov ксожалению создать свою схему вручную проблемно так как это шаблон проекта Web Application, SPA. Но я попробовал создать несколько разных проектов с разными вариантами, и как ожидалось результат одинаковый оказался во всех проектах "Входная строка имела не верный формат" может [он](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/661#issuecomment-436759693) и прав  что есть какая то проблема в провайдере. Раньше работал с PostgreSQL, не наблюдал таких странных исключений.

Comment: Как и ожидалось я устаовил PostgreSQL и всё решилось моментально больше. нет никаких входных строк и прочего нафталина! Делайти выводы

Comment: @ваняк, прошу прощения за некропост... «Делайте выводы»... делаем: Вы не разобрались в MySQL. А вот этой фразе место в блоге очередного изобличителя или на захудалом сайте отзывов о банках.